# CSS not showing up in my website Only HTML Displaying

Tags: wp-admin, css

I am very new to wordpress. I installed it on my linux server lately and uploaded a them on it. Everything looks good on my browser however if I try to access the website outside my network I am only getting the Text and not the CSS. I have read all different forum for the fix bt my problem still there. 
Here is my .htaccess

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

I have changed the permission to 755 and 777 restarted apache but still same issue.

Comment: Can you include a copy of your enqueue function from your `functions.php` file?

Comment: Are you using LAMP? WAMP? An actual ISP, like GoDaddy, that has linux or did you set up the linux server by yourself? The problems look a lot more like server problems and not WordPress. Also, when you respond here at StackExchange, use the "add a comment" link under the answer rather than using a new answer to respond.

Comment: I am using LAMP. I set up the linux server myself. It is on a raspberry pi 3. Jessie Lite. Sorry I am new to StackExchange

Answer (score 0):

Check you are addressing the CSS file correctly. How is it being called?

The url should be along the lines of `ht|tp://yoursite.com/wordpress/wp-content/themes/yourtheme/style.css` you'll find somewhere that it's loading as `ht|tp://localhost/`and so it will load correctly on your machine but not on anyone else's.

Have a look in Developer Tools for the URL of style.css

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with register script. Sample code

```
 wp_register_script('jquery', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/all.js', false, null);
wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
wp_register_style('all', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/all.css', false, null);
wp_enqueue_style('all');
```

If you have installed it in some folder, then your htaccess file should look like

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /yourfoldername/     -----> This line
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /barter3/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

If you are getting the text, then .htaccess might not be the problem.

Can u open the url in chrome browser, right click, inspect element, network 
-> Now refresh the page again
You will see styles tab in network
Click on it, it will show the url you are hitting for the css. Confirm your url is correct.

Answer (score 0):

You need to enter the full hostname and .local suffix into the WordPress Address and Site Address fields.

eg. http://raspberrypi.local

Answer (score -1):

Go to "General Settings" and set "wordpress address" and "site address" from your localhost address to your domain address...

Comment: Please **[edit] your answer**, and add an explanation: **why** could that solve the problem?